# Are there scenarios where the JSON payload from an AGOL webhook would have multiple collections in the array?

Tags: arcgis-online, json, iterator, integration

I have a webhook in AGOL that posts a JSON payload to an external system ([Integromat](https://www.integromat.com/en)).

- The webhook is triggered when features are edited in a feature layer (`Change Types: FeaturesEdited`).

[image]

---

This is what the JSON payload looks like:

```
[
   {
      "name":"Webhook 1",
      "layerId":0,
      "orgId":"Ak",
      "serviceName":"Work",
      "lastUpdatedTime":1597279482838,
      "changesUrl":"https://services.arcgis.com/Ak/arcgis/rest/services/Work/FeatureServer/extractChanges?serverGens=[4,7]&async=true&returnUpdates=false&returnDeletes=false&returnAttachments=false",
      "events":[
         "FeaturesCreated"
      ]
   }
]
```

---

Question:

I've noticed that the JSON collection in the payload is wrapped in an array.

Are there possible scenarios where multiple collections would be included in the array?

- Or can I safely assume that there will only ever be a single collection in the array and always point to the first colleciton?

Comment: *Why* questions about software engineering decisions can only be highly speculative if they are not asked of the development team.

Comment: @Vince OK. Thanks. I've modified the question.

Comment: If they have made it an array I think it is safe to assume that it will be possible in future, if not now.  We have no idea how they've implemented functions such as field calculations but it would seem sensible that these edits would be passed on a single webhook.

Comment: It could also have been that all the other requests supported arrays and it was just easier to leave the request signature alone, without any intention to provide  for multiples in the future.